# How to extend business logic by adding another rule without using of design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring, business-logic

I need your help. I got test project in which I'm returning `HTML table` full of employees information from `DB table` based on their roles.Currently there are 3 roles : Admin , Office Director and Delivery Manager.Admin can see all info ,Office director all employees from his office, and delivery manager all employees from his department regardless of office.Also employee can be office director at more than one office, he can be delivery manager at more than one department and last employee can be both delivery manager and office director.I didn't want to use any `design pattern` (`strategy,builder,factory)` because I've read that I should use it if there is more than 15-20 roles. I have this simple solution , but I'm not satisfied with it , because if in future I want to add another role , for example project manager , who can see something based on different query , it would be harder to implement that role in this solution , and code will be hard to maintain (especially if I add 2 or 3 roles, that is the maximum that I expect in future).

If anyone is kind to look at code and give me his thoughts or idea how can I refactor my code without using of design patterns, so it would be maintainable and opened for adding new roles(one or two).

There is another method which is returning list of employee roles `List<string> Positions`.
Then , based on roles, here is main part of `business logic` in my method I want you to look at and make suggestion.

```
public List<EmployeeRecord> GetListOfEmployeeInfo(Employee emp)
{
    List<EmployeeRecord> records = new List<EmployeeRecord>();
    if (emp.Positions.Contains("Admin")) 
    {// stored procedure that retrieves all info, 
     //there is no need to check if employee has another role, because as admin he can see everything} 
     else
     {
         if(emp.Positions.Contains("OfficeDirector") && emp.Positions.Contains("DeliveryManager"))
         {
           //stored procedure that returns distinct data for these 2 roles
         }
         else
         {
           if (emp.Positions.Contains("OfficeDirector"))
           {//recursive method that will retrieve all info in case employee is office director in more than 1 office, and stored procedure}
           if (emp.Positions.Contains("DeliveryManager"))
           {//recursive method that will retrieve all info in case employee is delivery manager on more than 1 department, and stored procedure}
         }
     }
 // ... further code to populate list of records etc

 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use stored procedures to fetch data?

Comment: `how can I refactor my code without using of design patterns, so it would be maintainable and opened for adding new roles(one or two).`

Umm... Design Patters make your code easier to maintain by encapsulating either logic or data, helping to decouple classes, etc.  I think your comment shows you aren't familiar with enough design patterns. NOT using design patterns would be a reason to refactor code.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei 
Yes I did.Beside DB table from which I'm fetching data , there is also similar SharePoint table for which I want to make similar solution .

Comment: @mawalker Yeah , you are right , I'm new to design patterns , and not familiar with them .

Comment: If you need a solution that does not require any C# coding to add a new role, you will have to transfer that bit of business logic to a StoredProc. In other words, all those `if` conditions that you use to check user role, will have to be written in your stored proc.

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't want to use any design pattern (strategy,builder,factory)
>   because I've read that I should use it if there is more than 15-20
>   roles.

I would say that wherever you read that.. was just an opinion, and that in 'my opinion' they are wrong/not clear enough.

Someone saying that you shouldn't use a pattern when you "only" have X number of Y(s) to deal with, is saying they don't feel the 'time' and 'effort' to understand/implement the pattern is worth it. But I would argue that isn't valid. Because the (proper) use of Design Patterns adds structure and predictability to your projects. If you descriptively name your classes and document well. Then at a very brief glance you should be able to quickly identify or eliminate classes as potential problems for what you are working on.

Such an example would be: "adding a new employee role", if you used strategy objects with a factory/builder, then all you would have to do is add your new 'role' to the list of roles, and then create a new strategy class. (possibly edit the builder/factory class/method that combines multiple roles logic together, but that would depend on specific implementation details, and could possibly be refactored out too)

---

My approach would use Enum to list the positions, Builder to build a 'query' (abstract meaning) that will return my results. and within that builder I'd use strategy pattern to create classes for each position's individual logic. Possibly use the Command Processor Pattern to actually process the Command object(s) of each strategy.

However this makes use of several patterns from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book) and http://www.openloop.com/softwareEngineering/patterns/designPattern/dPattern_CommandProcessor.htm